# Is there a relation between Shigaraki's power and how many hands does it have in his body?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I was watching a video of a Youtuber who covers My Hero Academia, and he made it sound like there is a relation between the amount of hands Shigaraki has attached to his body, and how much of his potential power he can release.

> He mentioned he lost some of his hands in one of the last chapters of the manga, #chapter 238 apparently

Is there a relation between Shigaraki's power and how many hands does it have in his body?

Answer (score 1):

In **Chapter 222**, it was mentioned that these hands somehow help Tomura Shigaraki calm down aside from making him nauseous. *If I recall correctly, this was the only function it had and serve no other purpose to Shigaraki or his power*.

Some of these [hands](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Tomura_Shigaraki) are recovered from Tomura's family when he accidentally killed them. The other hands from two unnamed street punks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. The reason he wears his the hands of his family and his first two victims is because of All For One. All For One wants to remind Shigaraki the power of his own bloodlust.

Answer (score -1):

No there is no relation from the amount of hands on the body to how powerful Shigaraki is. 
In the manga:

> > > Shigaraki loses the hands in a fight with the leader of the Liberation Army at the time, but is probably the strongest you can see Shigaraki up to this point in the manga. He actually isn't wearing any hands at some point in the fight but still is plenty strong.

Comment: But the theory is in the other direction I believe, that the less hands he has, the more power he can release. So what happened against the Liberation Army is congruent with that

Comment: @Pablo What theory are you talking about? Please clarify.